# Android cyclic gradle dependencies

Tags: android, proguard, android-library

I am trying to generate a release APK for Project A. it has a dependency on 2 imported libraries B and C which are also mine. B also has a dependency on C.
This creates a situation where A compiles C and also B compiles c.
This is the error:

> java.io.IOException: The same input jar
>   [/Users/Jon/android-app-manager/app/libs/**] is specified twice.

How is it possible to let gradle know the dependency has already been compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cyclic dependency in your description:

ProjectA --> LibB --> LibC

Gradle can manage [transitive dependencies](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html). All you have to do is :

- declaring a compile dependency to LibC in LibB (you already did that)
- declaring a compile dependency to LibB in ProjectA (you already did that)
- removing the explicit declaration of the dependency to LibC in ProjectA (gradle will find this transitive dependency automatically)